# Trying to repeat a pair of values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, repeat

I have a coordinate saved as a numpy array `x = np.array([1,2])` and I am trying to create an array that repeats [1,2] n times. For example, to repeat 4 times, I would want the array to look like this:

```
array([1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2])
```

I have tried using the function:

```
np.repeat(x, 4, axis=0)
```

but the output is flattened array that looks like this:

```
array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Check out numpy.tile https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html

Comment: When you are creating numpy, create with 2d

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way should be `[[1,2]]*4`

> `[[1,2]]*4`

`[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]`

If you wanna make it array, `np.array([[1,2]]*4)` would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2])
np.tile(x,[2,1])
>>> array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])

>>> np.tile(x,[4,1])
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: Good, We don't need to alter the original numpy array

Answer (score 0):

I defined a function for this problem. You can use below function called `repeatList`:

```
import numpy as np
myListToRepeat = [1,2]
def repeatList(initList , n):
    returnList = []
    for i in range(n):
        returnList.append(initList)
    return returnList
npArray = np.array(repeatList(myListToRepeat , 4))
print(npArray)
```

**Output**

```
[[1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give as below
You have to create an array which has 2 dimension
Then your inner array will an element for  axis=0. repeating will be done to

```
import numpy as np
num = np.array(([[1,2]]))
print(np.repeat(num,4,axis =0))#[[1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of numpy repeat use numpy tile. This fits your case:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t = np.array([1, 2])
>>> np.tile(t, 4)
array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Stil it is 1D array